# On the use of "is not so [...] but"

Tags: expressions, idioms, not-so-much-as

Is it proper English to say:

"With method A, the goal is not so to perform task B but (rather) to address problem C."

Are there other more appropriate/elegant ways to convey the same meaning?

Comment: The typical phrasing is "*not so **much** to*...". You may prefer to ask this question on our sister site for people new to English, [ELL.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use either "*not so much*" or "*not*", but not "*not so*".

1. *With A, the goal is not so much X as it is Y.*
2. *With A, the goal is not X but Y.*

The first means that the goal is more Y than X. The second means that the goal is not at all X; it is instead Y.

Comment: thanks. is proposition 1 adequate in writing? Or would you rather use another turn of phrase?

Comment: Dunno what you mean by *adequate in writing*? There is nothing particularly vulgar or informal about it, if that's what you are asking. It would occur in any kind of writing I'm familiar with.