# What does the negated comparative construction “not so much X as Y” mean?

Tags: meaning, negation, comparisons, not-so-much-as

On page 140 of [his 1976 book, *The Uses of Enchantment: The Meaning and 
Importance of Fairy Tales*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Uses_of_Enchantment), author Bruno Bettelheim writes:

> **The verses Falada speaks three times**—each time in response to the goose
>   girl’s lament on encountering its head: “Oh, Falada, thou who hangest
>   there”—**do not so much bemoan the girl’s fate as express the helpless grief 
>   of her mother.**  Falada’s implied admonition is that not only for her sake,
>   but also for her mother’sd, the princess should stop accepting passively
>   whatever happens to her.  It is also a subtle accusation that, had the
>   princess not ated so immaturely in dropping and losing the handkerchief and
>   in letting herself be pushed around by her maid, Falada would not have been
>   killed.  All the bad things that happen are the girl’s own fault because she
>   fails to assert herself.  Not even the talking horse can help her out of her
>   predicament.

I really had difficulty in understanding what that paragraph's first sentence means, the one that without the part surrounded by dashes runs

> The verses Falada speaks three times **do not so much bemoan** the girls fate **as express** the helpless grief of her mother.

Does it mean one of these three?

1. Falada doesn't bemoan the girl's fate as her (the girl's) mother does.
2. As Falada expresses her (the girl's) mother's helpless grief, he doesn't bemoan the girl's fate that much/
3. Although Falada expresses her mother's grief, he doesn't bemoan the girl's fate that much/

I thought if *express* were *expressing*, it would make more sense. Whatever it is, I still don't understand what it means.

Comment: Related and possible duplicates: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/53376 http://english.stackexchange.com/a/118055 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/137671 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/367060 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/364857  http://english.stackexchange.com/q/275761 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/240318 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/137671 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/62097  Please look those over and see whether they help clear this up for you.

Comment: In other words, the verses express the mother’s grief more than it bemoans the girl’s fate. It may well do both at the same time, but the focus is on the mother’s grief.

Comment: BTW, it's not a negated comparative; comparatives involve _-er_ or _more_, and _than_. The _as ... as_ construction is called an equative, not a comparative.