# What does this part of the sentence mean? "..where I had not so much arrived as simply stopped"

Tags: expressions, comparisons, not-so-much-as

"Perhaps because I was beginning to know all too well not indeed where I was going, but where I had not so much arrived as simply stopped"---whats the function of "as" before "simply stopped"

Comment: Related and possible duplicates: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/53376 http://english.stackexchange.com/a/118055 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/137671 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/367060 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/364857  http://english.stackexchange.com/q/275761 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/240318 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/137671 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/62097

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a comparison and a sub-comparison. We're comparing our plans (destination) to actual outcome (arrival), and then 'arrival' to 'stop'. Not only did we not get where we wanted to go, but it wasn't even a standard arrival (having the implication of having arrived 'somewhere'), just a cessation of motion.