# Would I use "as x with" or "so x with"?

Tags: grammar

For example, if I were to show a video of a person with sunglasses, and then tell a friend "You don't look as good with sunglasses" would this be correct? Or would "you don't look so good with sunglasses" be the correct term?

Comment: so good, as good are fine and mean different things. This can be googled, you know.

Comment: "You don't look so good with sunglasses" is ambiguous.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I cannot imagine how.

Comment: Related and possible duplicates: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/53376 https://english.stackexchange.com/a/118055 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/137671 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/367060 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/364857  https://english.stackexchange.com/q/275761 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/240318 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/137671 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/62097  Please look those over and see whether they help clear this up for you.

Comment: thanks a bunch, I googled it but gave me varying results

Comment: @tchrist and James, I think what Edwin's referring to is "you don't look so good" can have an idiomatic use that isn't really a comparison. It can be equivalent to "you don't look *very* good." In this case, there are really only two options (with or without sunglasses), but if you compare "You don't look so good today" and "You don't look as good today," the second makes an explicit comparison, while the first *could* or could not.

Comment: "You don't look as good as he/she does in sunglasses."

Comment: @Andy Bonner Saved me using the grey cells, thanks.